# Bitlocker does not detect my removable Hard-Drive, I cannot access it without restarting my computer

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, encryption, bitlocker

I have a problem concerning BitLocker and an external Hard-Drive.
(I am on Windows 10 and my hard drive is a WD Elements model.)

Sometimes, for a random reason my computer likes to forget that my removable hard drive has BitLocker encryption. So, instead of getting an image like this:
[image: Usual Drive list with Bitlocker recognizing the removable Hard-Drive]

and then allowing me to input my password:
[image: Password user input dialog box]

I have an image like this:
[image: Not usual Drive list with Bitlocker not recognizing the removable Hard-Drive]

And then, when trying to access it, I have a dialog box showing the following message:
[image: D:/ Drive access denied]

So i tried to do some things, like for instance restarting the bitlocker encryption service, but it didn't change anything.
I have these if it could help:

(when working for the C: Drive)
[image: CMD for the C: encryption]

(when working for the D: Drive)
[image: CMD for the D: encryption]

(when not working for the D: Drive)
[image: CMD for the D: encryption when not working]

I have also noted some actions that create the error like :

- branch the removable hard-drive after starting the computer (randomly because sometimes it recognize it);
- eject the removable hard-drive the right way (right click on the list of devices & printers).

If you have any idea how I could change this error, thank you.

Comment: I would try disabling BitLocker protection on the drive and then enabling BitLocker protection on the drive.

Answer (score 0):

The disk seems to be in a bad shape. It may be prudent to backup your
data off the disk before it becomes inaccessible and remove Bitlocker.

I would suggest :

- Check the Event Viewer for errors concerning the disk
- If the disk supports SMART, check its status
- Don't encrypt a disk that sometimes malfunctions and be prepared for
  it to fail.